# how to shorten url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Hello guys i need to shorten my url using htaccess
like

*Before*

> www.mysite.com/obj/task/profile/id/1568/username

*after*

> www.mysite.com/1568/username

or

*Before*

> www.mysite.com/obj/task/page/city/41280/pageId/22/clubs//Test%20town

*after*

> www.mysite.com/41280/22/clubs//Test%20town

how can i achieved this using htaccess

my htaccess file has this

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule (.*) index.php 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

***Suggested Changed***

```
<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
php_value memory_limit 170M

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule (.*) index.php


#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# THIS  RULE FOR FOR INACTIVE HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]  

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# from /obj/task/profile/id/1568/username
# to /1568/username
RewriteRule ^obj/task/profile/id(/.+)$/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

# from obj/task/page/city/41280/pageId/22/clubs//Test%20town
# to 41280/22/clubs//Test%20town
RewriteRule ^obj/task/page/city/([^/]+)/pageId(/.+?)/?$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

I have visited *www.mysite.com/obj/task/profile/id/1568/username*
The links is still not shorten.

Comment: Is `/obj/task/profile/id` OR `/obj/task/page/city/` part a static text?

Comment: what is static text?. Also when the user logs in and access his own profile the url is www.mysite.com/dtf/task/profile.

Comment: Do you want both to show the same page?  Or to redirect users visiting the longer to the shorter version?  Or redirect user visiting the shorter to the longer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shorten Url using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273560/shorten-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: i want users to be redirect to the shorter version

Comment: Can you provide some examples of before and after URLs.

Comment: just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# from /obj/task/profile/id/1568/username
# to /1568/username
RewriteRule ^obj/task/profile/id(/.+)$ /$1 [R=302,L,NC]

# from obj/task/page/city/41280/pageId/22/clubs//Test%20town
# to 41280/22/clubs//Test%20town
RewriteRule ^obj/task/page/city/([^/]+)/pageId(/.+?)/?$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: the url is still the long one.. :(

Comment: If you want URL to change in browser also add R flag. See my edit.

Comment: thanks for the help @anubhava.. i've tried the new command you have given but still not working. the url are still long

Comment: Ok pls provide your latest .htaccess (with my suggested changes) in your question and tell me what URI you used to test this?

Comment: just edited my question. i tried to visit the following link www.mysite.com/obj/task/profile/id/1568/username it show the page but when i visit www.mysite.com/1568/username it shows nothing.