# How to shorten a url in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, laravel-5.1

I have a wordpress website with the integration of a laravel5.1 app. I use a couple views from the laravel app. How can I shorten the the following url

http://wordpressapp.com/laravel-app/public/item/view/18

I would like to remove /larave-app/public/ from the url so that when they click on the link the url shows as

http://wordpressapp.com/item/view/18

I am not sure if I need to update the .htaccess file in the laravel-app/public folder or the .htaccess file in wordpress or in both files. Thanks

Comment: you can go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293605/how-to-shorten-u‌​rl-using-htaccess . this might help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an .htaccess expert but I know this trick has worked for me in the past:

```
RewriteRule ^laravel-app/public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

I imagine that the .htaccess file in the root of the site (WP) would need to be edited for this. I'm not sure what impact the "L" in the rule will have on the laravel app, perhaps it's worth giving it a try and testing?

This site: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ has some interesting explanations for you if you need more customisation.

Comment: From what I have read 'L' stands for (last- stop processing rule).

Comment: I tired your suggestion and restarted apache but had no luck thanks

Comment: Sorry Kyl, I hope you find a solution!