# .htaccess how to display long sub-directory urls as short urls in address bar?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days now. 
My root folder is https://www.example.com, I have many articles on it but in different folders and sub-folders for better organizing.

The problem is that I want links to look better and not like:

```
> https://www.example.com/reviews/review_1/index.html
                                 /review_2/index.html
                                 /review_3/index.html
```

or

```
https://www.example.com/articles/blog/content_1/index.html
                                     /content_2/index.html
                                     /content_3/index.html
```

but instead, I want all folders under "reviews and articles" to appear like root/dirs:

```
https://www.example.com/review_1/index.html
https://www.example.com/content_1/index.html
```

...so is it possible to exclude `../reviews/` or `../articles/blog/` folder somehow, but to have the same directory structure and also not to have duplicate content, indexes or duplicate DIRs?

EDIT / I found the solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^review_1/(.*) reviews/review_1/$1
```

This code will redirect from folder `reviews/review_1/` to unexisting folder `review_1` on root and copy all content from `reviews/review_1/` to `review_1`.

Comment: look into rewrite rules

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule` look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293605/how-to-shorten-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

just create an associative arrow specifying the mapping between url's and what they mean under the hood, for example I use in php like this-

```
$route = array(
   array(
    'url' => 'review_1/index.html',
    'map_to' => '/articles/blog/reviews/index.html'
  ),
   array(
  )
);
```

or better version like implementing simple routing-

`$route = array(
       array(
        'url' => '/review/',
        'controller' => 'controller_class',
        'action' => 'model_class'
      ),
       array(
      )
    );`

better proceed with second process..
do some research in implementing routing yourself or use basic framework.
Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no knowledge of php, so it's a little problem to solve this in the suggested way. I was hoping if there is any .htaccess code I can implement?

Comment: you can specify override rules but for each individual requests it's little difficult to manage.

Comment: you can write like this-  RewriteRule {pattern_to_be_matched}   {pattern maps to this} [flags]